# Unable to Open Windows 8 app samples. Is it because I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I downloaded the Windows 8 app samples (C#) from here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-app-samples-4d76cbbf

I'm trying to open them with **Visual Studio 2012 Express 2012 for Windows Phone** and I'm getting the following error window:

[image]

The complete text of which is here:

> Unsupported
>
> This version of Visual Studio does not have the following
>   project types installed or does not support them. You can still open
>   these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were
>   originally created.
>      - AccelerometerCS, "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Windows 8 app samples\C#\Windows 8 app samples\Accelerometer sensor sample (Windows
>   8)\C#\AccelerometerCS.csproj"
>
> No changes required
>
> These projects can be opened in this version of
>   Visual Studio without changing them. They will continue to open in
>   Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and in this version of Visual Studio.
>      - AccelerometerCS, "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Windows 8 app samples\C#\Windows 8 app samples\Accelerometer sensor sample (Windows
>   8)\C#\AccelerometerCS.sln"

Is there something I can do to load these samples that doesn't involve me buying the full Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Express versions of Visual Studio are targeted to support specific platforms only.

The version for Windows Phone will only open Windows Phone projects.

To open Windows [8] projects you'll need the appropriate version of Visual Studio Express which is available from http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2013-preview